# Unexplainable usage of parentheses in the declaration

Tags: c

I found this [piece of C code](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/split-wide/system-calls-or-bust.html#getaddrinfoprepare-to-launch):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the address itself,
        // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else { // IPv6
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

    return 0;
}
```

There are two lines that I don't know how to interpret:

```
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
```

```
struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
```

Why does the author of this program use *parentheses*?

I tried following a wonderful guide about [interpreting complex declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/interpreting-more-complex-declarators?view=msvc-170) but I still don't understand.

Comment: Anything to the right of `=` is an initializer, and is just an expression, not specific to declarations. Those parentheses are a *type cast*.

Comment: It's casting `p->ai_addr` from a `struct sockaddr *` to a more specific type, namely `struct sockaddr_in6 *`

Answer (score -2):

It's called casting. It converts from one type to another, but the theory behind it is a lot more complicated. Casting doesn't mean you have an object describing a `Dog` (for example a struct) and you can cast it to a `Human`. Obviously you can't.

Casting means having identical memory blocks that can map on another block. A simpler explanation is when you have a complex structure and you cast from a pointer to the structure or from the data structure to the pointer.

Also note, that a data structure doesn't necessarily mean a `struct`. It can also mean an array. And, an **array** is a concept so it can mean something like `int some_data[20];` or `int** some_data;`.

Now, as for why the author uses the parenthesis, it's because this is the syntax. You can't use any character.
Along with further reading about casting, please look up `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`. These 3 functions (well, almost, but I'm trying to not complicate it even more) use native casting. `static_cast` is similar to `(type_a*)type_b`.

For some examples, look up casting from `int` to `enum` and vice-versa to get an idea.

If you want to keep it *simple*, don't check any C++ concepts about casting just yet until you get a hang of the concepts in C first. They are common, but C++ will fork a lot from C because of classes, polymorphism and inheritance in general.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++. Most of your answer is irrelevant

Comment: Which part is about C++ apart from the disclaimer at the end? Casting structs or pointers is common in C, as well as PODs, including old enums as well as scoped enums if using the new standard. Using pointers of pointers is also common in C.

Comment: I did not point more problems in this answer like the **array** part

Comment: "Casting means having identical memory blocks that can map on another block. " is also amiss.  `int x = (int) 1.234:` is a cast and has nothing to do with identical memory blocks.  OP's use involves casting a pointer, a subset of casting possibilities.

Comment: Did you really want me to go into detail and explain to him the memory management inside C? I tried to oversimplify and state that if the data is identical, then it can cast. If you have 2 structs, each of different sizes or even same size, but the data types in different order, surely while you can force a cast, it won't mean it is correct. I am sure you can guess I was not talking about number to int casting.